# How can i transfer elements from queue to stack?

Tags: c++, queue, stack

A queue `Q` containing `n` items and an empty stack `s` are given. It is required to transfer all the items from the queue to the stack so that the item at the front of queue is on the TOP of the stack, and the order of all other items are preserved.

I tried coding it but it only prints the elements of queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void Stack(queue<int>& q)
{
    queue<int> s;

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        q.push(s.top());
        q.pop();
    }

    while(!s.empty())
    {
        s.push(q.front());
        s.pop();
    }

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        q.push(s.top());
        q.pop();
    }
}

void printStack(queue<int> a)
{

    while(!a.empty())
    {
       cout<<a.front()<<" ";
       a.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);
    q.push(4);

    cout<<"Queue: ";
    printStack(q);

    cout<<"Stack: ";


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well all you do is create the queue, then call `printStack` to print the queue (not stack).

Comment: Your Stack Function is incorrect. s is an queue but there is no top() function. Even if you try to push an element from an uninitialized queue.

Comment: That first while-loop is nonsense. You use `s.top()`. But `s` is `queue<int>` (and an empty one at that). . A `queue` has no `top()` method. So this code doesn't print *anything* because it doesn't even compile. Does your *real* code declare `s` as `stack<int> s;` ? If it does, it still isn't right, since `s.top()` isn't legit until `s` contains data (which it wouldn't). I think you need to explain that function carefully to [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: this is the one that i followed: `Do
Delete an item from Q
Push the item to S
While (! empty Q); 
Do
Pop an item from S
Insert the item to Q
While (! empty S); 
Do
Delete an item from Q
Push the item to S
While (! empty Q); `

Comment: Sould i create a stack and put the `s.top()`?

Comment: Nope you didn't. You push to Q from S. Or at least you tried. Btw. s is still a queue and no stack.

Comment: May I suggest something else. Do not use using namespace. In your code there is a difference between stack and Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transfer function (`Stack`) is wrong. The exercise it to use the queue and the stack to:

- Empty the queue by pushing each element on to the stack.
- Empty the stack by popping each element and pushing it into the queue
- Empty the queue by pushing each element on to the stack.

The result will produce a stack whose `top` is the same as the original queue's `front`.

It should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

stack<int> Stack(queue<int>& q)
{
    stack<int> s;  // notice : stack, not queue

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        s.push(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }

    while (!s.empty())
    {
        q.push(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        s.push(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{    
    queue<int> q;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
        q.push(i);

    // transer the queue to a stack
    stack<int> s = Stack(q);

    // print (and empty) the stack.
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        std::cout << s.top() << ' ';
        s.pop();
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```